# How can I show my C# data table, that I have created in the razor-codebehind file, in my razor page? (Blazor server side Project)

Tags: c#, razor, datatable, blazor-server-side

I have created a data table in my razor.cs file with C# and filled it with data. I want to show this datable in my razor page on screen in html table format. How can I do that?
Is it possible to show the data table in total, or do I have to show the elements one by one? I have tried in this way but get always the error:
System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named '---' already belongs to this DataTable. The table comes empty/

```
 public DataTable Programs_WMI_total = new DataTable();

 for(int m=1; m< Programs_WMI_total.GetLength(1);m++)
            {
                Programs_WMI_name_sorted[m] =    WMI_Programs_table.Rows[m][0].ToString();
                Programs_WMI_publisher_sorted[m] = WMI_Programs_table.Rows[m][1].ToString();
                Programs_WMI_installdate_sorted[m] = WMI_Programs_table.Rows[m][2].ToString();
                Programs_WMI_installlocation_sorted[m] = WMI_Programs_table.Rows[m][3].ToString();
            }
```

on the razor side:

```
 @{if (@Programs_WMI_name[0] != null && Programs_number!=0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class=table_header>Program name</td>
                <td class=table_header>Publisher</td>
                <td class=table_header>Install. date</td>
                <td class=table_header>Install. path</td>
            </tr>
            for (var i = 0; i < Programs_number; i++)
            {
                if (@Programs_WMI_name[i] != "")
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Programs_WMI_name_sorted[i]</td>
                        <td>@Programs_WMI_publisher_sorted[i]</td>
                        <td>@Programs_WMI_installdate_sorted[i]</td>
                        <td>@Programs_WMI_installlocation_sorted[i]</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are somehow trying to insert the same data 2x, probably by initializing it in `OnInitialized()`.  But your code as you've shared it doesn't really make much sense: you create a DataTable and then immediately iterate based on its length as though it's supposed to contain anything.